is {.....,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4} same as (-infinity,4]?
Like can you write them interchangeably, instead of writing {....,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4} , can you write  (-infinity,4] , or do they both mean different things?

Usually, $(-\infty,4]$ means all real numbers less than or equal to $4$, not just the integers less than or equal to $4$.

So we will not use this in case of integers but only when it is real numbers?

The interval notation is usually for subsets of real numbers.

If you want a different way to denote ${ \ldots, -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}$, you can write ${x\in \mathbb{Z}: x \leq 4}$, but the former is fine too.

@Hani It depends on what you mean by "....".

"...." doesn't this only mean one thing?

@Hani By ${3,5,7,\ldots}$, I mean the set of positive odd integers or the set of odd prime numbers?

As Arturo Magidin already said: $(—\infty, 4]$ includes all real numbers less than or equal to 4, while {…, 3, 4} only contains the integers less than or equal to 4. As such, the current definitions of the sets allows the following to be true:
For $\pi = 3.14 \dots$ 
$\pi \in (—\infty, 4]$ but $\pi \notin \{…, 3, 4\}$.
Essentially,
$(—\infty, 4] \neq \{\dots, 3, 4\}$
To force these sets to be equal, its common to use intersection: $(—\infty, 4] \cap \mathbb{Z}$. This way both sets only include the integers less than or equal to 4.
$(—\infty, 4] \cap \mathbb{Z} = \{…, 3, 4\}$.
